# is there is a way to generate, create or export a .ppt presentation on iOS using C or C++ library

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I have a UIView contains subviews which appear with animation, how can i generate a .ppt or .keynote presentation with this UIView included the subviews animation.

Thank You

Comment: Keynote's format is proprietary. The .ppt is open source, and while it's possible you might find a C++ or C library, I doubt it. I support  Excel read/write libaries, and they are huge and terribly complex. I imagine implementing the .ppt format would be many staff-years of work.

Comment: Have u got any solution for this?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it is possible. Closest you can get would be examining the Open Document Format and trying to create a tool that creates ODF documents. They can be exported to PPT. However, there is no out-of-the-box solution you can use. You would need to write it.

You can have a look at this project that allow programmatic creation, scanning and manipulation of ODF documents:
http://wiki.apache.org/incubator/ODFToolkitProposal

It's in Java but should give you an idea.